# What does the complement mean as it relates to Boolean Algebra?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

For a lattice to be a Boolean Algebra it must be a distributive lattice and contain complements. What does the word complement mean?

Answer (score 6):

A *complemented lattice* is a bounded lattice (with least element 0 and greatest element 1), in which every element a has a *complement*, i.e. an element $b$ such that

$$a \lor b = 1\quad\text{and}    \quad a \land b = 0.$$

---

In general an element may have more than one complement. However, in a bounded **distributive lattice** every element will have at most one complement. A lattice in which every element has exactly one complement is called a uniquely complemented lattice.

[A lattice with the property that every interval is complemented is called a relatively complemented lattice. In other words, a relatively complemented lattice is characterized by the property that for every element a in an interval [c, d] there is an element b such that

$$a \lor b = d\text{ and} \;\;a\land b = c.$$

Such an element b is called a complement of a relative to the interval.]

A distributive lattice is *complemented* if and only if it is *bounded* and *relatively complemented*.

***Boolean algebras*** are a special case of *orthocomplemented lattices*, which in turn are a special case of complemented lattices (with extra structure). These structures are most often used in quantum logic, where the closed subspaces of a separable Hilbert space represent quantum propositions and behave as an orthocomplemented lattice.

*Orthocomplemented lattices, like Boolean algebras*, satisfy de Morgan's laws:

$$(a \lor b)^\perp = a^\perp \land b^\perp$$

$$(a \land b)^\perp = a^\perp \lor b^\perp.$$

Comment: I dono much about Boolean so +